# Erlang Phash implementation

Tags: erlang, hash

I'm trying to reproduce the exact behavior of [Erlang phash](http://www.erlang.org/documentation/doc-5.2/lib/kernel-2.8.0/doc/html/erlang.html#erlang%3aphash%2) in another language (Ruby for example). Does anyone know the details of its implementation?

Basically, if in Erlang :
`erlang:phash(X, n) -> Y`
I want that
`phash(X,n) = Y`  in Ruby.

Comment: First off, you should copy `phash2`, unless there's a specific requirement to match `phash`. The bigger problem, however, is that phash and phash2 are specifically designed for Erlang's type system. Do you want to implement a precise mirror that generates the same hash in both languages, or just copy the basic idea? Even copying the idea is fraught, because Erlang's type system is essentially fixed in stone. It has no conception of classes, user-defined types or information hiding.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have much of a choice, as I need to reproduce the exact pattern used by ejabberd when load-balancing components and it uses `phash`.

Comment: Your pushing uphill with this problem. Perhaps you could describe what you are trying to accomplish at a higher level. There may be another way to do what you want.

Comment: Sure. We're building a an application that pushes incoming XMPP traffic into some comet and/or websocket traffic. It's important that we have horizontal scalability because we can quickly have millions of downstream websocket/comet open. We then need to load balance on both ends, using ejabberd's component load balancing (http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/guide_en#domainlb) and HAProxy's load balancing. Obviously, the 2 hash functions need to be identical, or we will lose messages (if a message is sent to component A, while the comet is on B, we're screwed :p)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see how it works, check the original code: https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/cbd1378ee1fde835e55614bac9290b281bafe49a/erts/emulator/beam/utils.c#L644

But you cannot have "exact" behaviour of phash in another language - simply because you don't have erlang's datatypes available there. (unless you create your own mappings of course)

Comment: Ouch. How hard do you think it would be to create the same mappings?

Comment: I think it would be very very error-prone. What do you think about using something like: http://www.igvita.com/2009/03/20/ruby-polyglot-talking-with-erlang/ to send your data back to erlang for proper hashing?

Comment: Hum. I don't really need it in Ruby, because it won't be executed in Ruby anyway. It's just to build the exact same mapping into HAProxy. So ideally, I will have to re-create that in C. Ruby was just to avoid pseudo-code :)